# HTML Drop Down Menu to Redirect to Another Page

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to create a drop-down list in HTML; when a user selects an item from the list, he/she should be redirected accordingly to another web page. That code will be integrated into a Laravel blade (this is the reason for the csrf field). I have the following code, but when clicking the search button, I don't go to `/research` page (though I have already created the route). Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Select departmnent</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="/research" id="tmima">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    Choose department:<br>
</form>
<select name="Department" id="tmima">
    <option value="0" selected="selection">Select</option>
    <option value="geo">Geology</option>
    <option value="phs">Physics</option>
    <option value="chm">Chemistry</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are closing the form before the select input, remove the `</form>` and place it at the ending of your form.

```
<form method="post" action="/research" id="tmima">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  Choose department:<br>

// Here was the </form>, remove it here

  <select name="Department" id="tmima">
    <option value="0" selected="selection">Select</option>
    <option value="geo">Geology</option>
    <option value="phs">Physics</option>
    <option value="chm">Chemistry</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form> // <-- place it here, it will work
```

**EDIT:**

As you wrote in the comments, you can use the select outside the form. But you need to tell your select that it belongs to the form. This is done via the `form` attribute of the select: You need to add it to your select like this:

```
...
<select name="Department" form="tmima"> //replace the id with form
...
```

Comment: Thanks, this was correct! It was so simple! I was based on this https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_form.asp   and I had placed the drop list outside the <form>.

Comment: Glad I could help you. Please consider marking my answer as correct (the green hook on the left), so that other people can see that this has solved your problem :)

Comment: Ok! I just did it!

Comment: I've edited my answer, you can use the select outside of the form, but you need to tell it that it belongs to the form.

Comment: After submitting this form, every selection redirects to /research. How can I redirect according to selection? For example I want if Geology is selected to go to /redirect, if Physics is selected to go to /redirect1 and if Chemistry is selected to go to /redirect3. Could you help me a little?

Comment: Thats not what selects are for. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I'm thinking of creating separate blades. For example a geology student should select geology from the list and he/she should be directed to the relevant blade. When at the blade, he should enter his/her id to retrieve his results. The same goes for Physics, Chemistry etc.

Comment: But you usally don't want to place your form logik into different files. I would redicret to one route that handles the form (e.g. `/formlogik`) and after I handled the form request and then redirect based on the selected element (`return redirect('biology')`)